# I am creating a add task app and when I ran the app I get an error that says 'type "Null" is not a subtype of type "String"

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I have two classes namely; the add task screen and task screen. The add task screen is a class made from the floating action button that shows a modal screen for adding the tasks and when selected will add to the task list screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function addTaskCallback;

  const AddTaskScreen(this.addTaskCallback,{super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? newTaskTitle;

    return Container(
      color: const Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding:  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, right: 45.0, left: 45.0, bottom: 20.0),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Add Task',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              ),
            ),
             TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (newText){
                newTaskTitle = newText;
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: const ButtonStyle(
                elevation: MaterialStatePropertyAll(1.0),
                backgroundColor:
                    MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.lightBlueAccent),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                  addTaskCallback(newTaskTitle);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the task screen is made up of both the add task screen class and task list screen. but most of the error I am facing has to do with both the add task screen and task screen, although the add task screen will update the tasks to the task list.
this is the task screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:state_mgt/screens/task_lists.dart';

import '../models/task.dart';
import 'add_task.dart';

class TaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TaskScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TaskScreen> createState() => _TaskScreenState();
}

class _TaskScreenState extends State<TaskScreen> {
  List<Task> tasks = [
    Task(name: 'Buy milk'),
    Task(name: 'Buy egg'),
    Task(name: 'Buy fish'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen(
              (newTaskTitle) {
                tasks.add(Task(name: newTaskTitle));
                print(newTaskTitle);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 30.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
            child: const Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  radius: 25.0,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.list,
                    size: 25.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Text(
                  'Todoey',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 35.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  '12 Tasks',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: TaskList(tasks),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when I ran this everything checks out, however when I try to add a task I get this error.
[image: error message shows a null]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your TaskScreen widget you declare

```
String? newTaskTitle;
```

in your build method, which is bad practice, because every time you call setState your newTaskTitle will be set to null again.

Move your newTaskTitle outside your build, make it a member variable inside your state so it doesn't get reset in your onChanged from your TextField.